цикл while true в python
Вопрос по завершению цикла while при парсинге
offset = 1

while True:
    website = f'https://new.zonafilm.ru/api/series?page={offset}'
    usag = fake_useragent.UserAgent().random
    random_usag = {"User-Agent": usag}
    respon = requests.get(website, headers=random_usag).json()
    data = respon.get('data')
    files = []
    for item in data:
        if 'description' in item :
            files.append({
                'title': item.get('title'),
                'desc': item.get('description'),
                'image': item.get('cover_url')

            })
        else:
            break

    print(files)
    offset += 1

После того, как цикл прошелся по всем страницам, вместо завершения функции на экран выводит скобки [], хотя в условиях обозначил, что должно быть завершение.
Прошу пнуть в нужном направлении, где допустил ошибку, к сожалению, сам не могу дойти до решения.
Заранее спасибо, и извиняюсь за, возможно, глупый вопрос.

break выходит из цикла for.  а из цикла while - нет.

По большому счёту, у Вас проблема не с циклом while а с архитектурой кода.

@strawdog, break не выходит даже из цикла for потому что на пустом списке тело цикла не выполняется.

Walrus
Моржовый (walrus) оператор, появившийся в Python 3.8,
дает возможность решить сразу две задачи:

присвоить значение переменной
вернуть это значение



Первое, files = [] должен быть вне цикла while.
Второе, напиши функцию get_data(offset), в ней это всё: website, usag, random_usag
и вызывай её в условии цикла:
def get_data(offset):
    if offset < 11:
        return f"offset == {offset}"
    else:
        return None

offset = 1

while data := get_data(offset):
    # далее обработка...
    print(data)
    offset += 1



Для оператора ”walrus” есть PEP 572,
начните знакомство с раздела Примеры (Examples)

Можно тогда и тернарный оператор добавить, что бы ретурнов не городить:  return f"offset == {offset}" if offset < 11 else None

@Amgarak Можно, но автор и его выкинет - т.к. выстроит в функции свою логику... :)

Если уж разделять на функции, то гораздо логичнее делить на генератор, который получает все страницы или даже все данные, а на постраничное получение, заставляющее каждый раз при использовании писать обёртку с циклом и счётчиком страниц.

@Qwertiy Вот именно такой ответ был бы под стать Вашей репутации в 125,568 баллов! От модераторов-наставников пользы больше, чем от модераторов-полицаев. Надеюсь, Вы поймёте мой (наш) message...

Раз уж некоторые хотят архитектурно красивое решение, то, по-моему, надо делать так (не смог проверить, надеюсь, работает):
def get_data():
  offset = 1

  while True:
    website = f'https://new.zonafilm.ru/api/series?page={offset}'
    usag = fake_useragent.UserAgent().random
    random_usag = {"User-Agent": usag}
    respon = requests.get(website, headers=random_usag).json()
    data = respon.get('data')

    if data:
      yield from data
    else:
      break

    offset += 1

files = [{
  'title': item.get('title'),
  'desc': item.get('description'),
  'image': item.get('cover_url')
} for item in get_data()]

print(files)

Поведение здесь отличается от того, что в вопросе, поскольку там через print выводилась каждая страница в отдельности, а тут - только все данные вместе.

Если нужно изменить так, чтобы вывод появлялся по мере появления данных, надо сделать вывод по одной строке с помощью
for item in get_data():
  print({
    'title': item.get('title'),
    'desc': item.get('description'),
    'image': item.get('cover_url')
  })


Если важны именно страницы, то надо выкинуть отсюда from
yield from data

После чего в цикле for обрабатывать страницы:
for items in get_data():
  files = [{
    'title': item.get('title'),
    'desc': item.get('description'),
    'image': item.get('cover_url')
  } for item in items]

  print(files)


PS: В зависимости от задачи может быть удобнее перенести маппинг внутрь функции получения данных.

Спасибо за вклад, успехов!

спасибо, принял!

@kbasel_71, прими один из ответов нажатием на галочку слева от него.

Так у тебя вообще выхода из цикла в коде нет.
if not data: break


поэтому и задал свой вопрос, по логике ищем 'description' на всех страницах, когда они заканчиваются искать уже нечего и срабатывает  else: break

@kbasel_71 break завершает цикл for, а не while, т.к. находится внутри цикла for.

Минус мой, Вы знаете моё отношение к костылям. (Ему в принципе не нужен while True:)

@kbasel_71, так я ж сказал, какую строчку добавить...

@AnnaBazueva, а почему собственно это костыль? Если бы у него не было print, в большинстве языков можно было бы использовать do-while, но гугл говорит, что do while в питоне как раз пишется как while true с break по условию внутри. А при наличии print внутри выход вообще нужен внутри тела, а значит это очевидный if break.

@kbasel_71, возможно, надо проверять не data, а len(data).

Внешняя итерация по страницам сайта, априори конечна, а цикл while (как Вы верно отметили) по природе условный. После обработки последней страницы, вызов get_data(offset) вернёт None — условие выхода из цикла. Вы предложили решение для while True:, но у него проблема с архитектурой. Так что в контексте это костыль.

@AnnaBazueva, я не согласен с этим.
